# Conductor completely surrounds another conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conductors

A problem in my book asks to

"Demonstrate that the capacitance of any conductor is always smaller than or equal to the capacitance of a conductor which can completely surround it".

The solution to this is obvious to me for conductors which are concentric and have poloidal/azimuthal symmetry because all of the integrals involved are then very easy. However, if one has irregularly shaped conductors, is there some generalization of the integrations that can be used to show this result?

Comment: Try to show what happens if you make a very small perturbation to the surface - if it's outward, what happens to the field distribution? Once you have established this for a small deviation, you can integrate to get any shape you want.

Comment: When you say perturbation, do you mean like giving the sphere a small spiky part? Or do you mean increasing the radius of the sphere by some small amount? The latter has an obvious result, but the former seems intractable to me.

Comment: I mean - add a small "bump" like you would get if a small sphere extended slightly from the surface. You know the field due to a small sphere, and due to the big sphere. See if you can get anywhere with superposition. I suspect it can be done.

Comment: After trying a bit, I'm not sure if understand yet.

Comment: If you move a small part of the charged surface outwards you will lower the energy (because of repulsion from the other charges). If charges subsequently redistribute, they do so to lower their energy even more.

Comment: Ok, so you are basically saying that the potential energy required to hold the charges on a larger surface is less because they can more sparsely populate the sphere? Do you think there are more rigorous solutions? Like maybe trying to represent the charge distributions as Dirac Delta surfaces? Or using Gauss' law with the normal vector for the area written as the gradient of a scalar function representing the surface of the conductor?

Comment: There is no doubt a more rigorous approach but I can't think of one. But yes the mean distance between charges will be greater if the surface area is greater. But since it is possible to conceive of any irregular "inner" conductor with greater area than a spherical "outer" conductor I agree it needs a bit more than that

Comment: But even if you have an irregular conductor, you could circumscribe it with a slightly larger one that will still have a large area and thus a larger mean distance..?

Comment: Yes but you could also circumscribe it with one that has a smaller area. But if you do, I suppose all the charges must have moved in the direction of the electric field (positive dot product) so net energy goes down and capacitance goes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's interesting because the proof needs a relationship between Gauss's Law, which involves a surface internal of $\vec{E}$, and a definition of potential difference, which involves a line integral of $\vec{E}$.

If you consider just the original conductor with a positive charge, and place a Gaussian surface at the position of the outer conductor, the average electric field component perpendicular to the surface (spatially averaged over the surface) is pointing outward. Some point in the surface must actually have that value. Since the electric field points toward lower potential, the inside has higher potential. Repeat for a progression of surfaces that interpolate the space between the two conductors. That establishes that the inner surface is at higher potential than the order surface.

Work the Gaussian surfaces in the other direction (toward infinity) and you can establish that if either surface is given the same positive charge, the outer one will be at a lower potential. Therefore the outer one has more capacitance.

Comment: Since its the average, and conductors are equal potential surfaces, doesn't that mean that the average is actually just THE potential?

Comment: @Loonuh, not quite.  The average I mentioned is an average of $E_\perp$.  Equipotential refers to the potential, not the field.

Comment: Is there a way to more rigorous show that? What about trying to express the densities as uniformly distributed at arbitrary surfaces? Or rewriting Gauss' law as $\int \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla f = Q/\epsilon_0$ where f is the equation of the surface?

Comment: @Loonuh Yes, probably.  My hunch is that it involves switching the order of the linear operations, gradient and surface integral.  Another likely tool is some form of the Mean Value Theorem or the Intermediate Value Theorem.